# How to view assembly language produced by VS2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

How can I see the assembly language my C++ project has been compiled into within VS2010?

Comment: Please be specific.  Which language and platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supply /FAcs to the command line, or select "Assembler Output" under the project properties → C/C++ → Output Files.

The compiler emits an .asm file next to the .o file corresponding to the .cpp. You can learn more about the operation of /FAcs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367y26c6.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: It is really very strange that this post was marked as an answer, because it is not the answer and cannot be such. The question is "how to view". You are telling us "how to create".

Comment: @Gangnus Once you have emitted the assembly file using /FAcs, you may then view it in a text editor.

Comment: 1. It is quite obvious. But where it the listing and how it is named? 2. Existence of comment changes nothing on the fact that your post is not the answer on the question. The question is: how to view **produced** file.  Reread the title.

Comment: @Gangnus The compiler emits an .asm file next to the .o file corresponding to the .cpp. You can learn more about the operation of /FAcs here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/367y26c6.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thank you. I added that info to the answer. +1.

Answer (score 0):

It's not assembly language, but MSIL.  You can use MSIL Disassembler to view MSIL from an assembly (.dll or .exe) : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(v=vs.80).aspx

Even better than that is a tool like Reflector: http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx?TreatAsUpdate=1 - a bit more interactive.

Edit: Note, I am assuming managed code here.

Answer (score 0):

You can either view it directly in VS by debugging your app and right click -> show dissambly, or you can use an external debugger/dissambler (olydbg or MASM for example). Either, you can go to yours solution properties -> C/C++ -> Output files -> Assembler Output